# Change the style with the MouseMove event Listener in ReactJs

Tags: css, reactjs, jsx

I would like to movemy mouse cursor in react js and apply some style after it coincides with my charachter for example !! In my case I woule like it to apply it in my letter `Z` !!

```
<span className='letterZ animate__animated animate__zoomIn delay1'>Z</span>

const [MousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
left: 0,
top: 0
})
function handleMouseMove(ev) {
setMousePosition({
left: ev.pageX,
top: ev.pageY
      });
  }
```

So I defined a cursor div in the last part of my section !! Here is the code

```
<div className="cursor" onMouseMove={handleMouseMove} style={{left:MousePosition.left , top: MousePosition.top
}}></div>
```

But the when I display my content the div `cursor` is stacked in the screen above becauz by defualt my state is set to left 0 and top 0

Here is my code CSS

```
.cursor{
position: fixed;
width:20px;
height:20px;
border-radius:50%;
background:#fff;
transition:0.1s;
transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
pointer-events:none;
mix-blend-mode: difference;
}
.letterZ:hover ~.cursor{
transform:scale(6)
}
```

Comment: I would add another state with ```[visible, setVisible]``` and then apply that either through css or directly in the style object ```style={{display: visible ? 'block' : 'none'}}```

Answer (score 0):

```
const [MousePosition, setMousePosition] = useState({
left: 0,
top: 0
})
const cursor = document.querySelector(".cursor")
cursor.onmousemove = function(event) {
setMousePosition({
left: event.pageX,
top: event.pageY
      });
  }
<div className="cursor" style={{left:MousePosition.left , top: MousePosition.top
}}></div>
```